# OSX NSUserDefaults not Working

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults

This code gives me always NO in my application. It does indeed work in any other project I copy it... so something must be messed up with my standardUserDefaults, but I absolutely don't know how this can happen and how to solve it!

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"myKey"];

BOOL test = [defaults boolForKey:@"myKey"];
// test is ALWAYS NO here!
```

Can anybody hint me, where to start or how to get rid of this?

It's a mixed project with swift and objective c and get the same behavior in me AppDelegate.swift, when I put this directly in my applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()        
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "myKey")

let test = defaults.boolForKey("myKey")
// test ALWAYS false here
```

Before someone asks:
- yes, even with synchronize called between it
- yes this is the whole code, nothing between the lines... set and get it right after does not work

Comment: How are you checking the value of `test`?

Comment: Check with: `NSLog(test ? @"Yes" : @"No");` Btw for anyone wondering about this syntax its called ternary opertator.

Comment: I checked it with NSLog and directly in the debugger with a breakpoint. Also used synchronize and checked in the file... the files is never created! - But I found something: When I change my bundle Identifier it works... But I can't change this! It's registered in itunes connect (it's a sandboxed appstore app) - And the app worked before and I can't figure out a change in my version control when this behavior started... NEVER changed the bundle id.

Comment: My app itself does never user NSUserDefaults, it's other libraries like dropbox.framework or the Google API. I don't know what to register for them, I only got so far they are failing, because NSUserDefaults is not storing any information. - and changing the bundle id just worked once. after deleting the container and entries in the keychain to startover and test again a fresh install, it fails again... Is there something I miss to delete (even removed the derivedData from XCode)

Comment: found this: https://ind.ie/labs/blog/app-sandbox-updating-nsuserdefaults-fails-after-deleting-apps-container-directory/ - But even with empty trash it was not recreated or working again..

Comment: If you've ever manually deleted an app's preferences file, probably best to log out and log back in.

Comment: from osx? I tried, nothing changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution, how to fix it, but not why this happens and no clean, good way so far.

If anybody could explain this and give me a better solution, do so!

1. the problem was:
   If you delete the container of a sandboxed app, you also delete the plist for the NSUserDefaults and it's not created again and so NSUserDefaults simply is not working.
2. the workaround: 
   As I found here https://ind.ie/labs/blog/app-sandbox-updating-nsuserdefaults-fails-after-deleting-apps-container-directory/ it's a problem with the permanent bookmark of the system.
   Well just to empty the trash does not work for me, but what worked: I simply created the missing file!

   ```
   touch ~/Library/Containers/com.example.myapp/Data/Library/Preferences/com.example.myapp.plist
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This saved me possibly hours.