# Dropbox Datastore to API 2 Migration Error

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm trying to provide a way in my iOS app to migrate existing Datastore users to a new means of storing an SQLite database file on Dropbox via the new v2 API (SwiftyDropbox).

I'm currently trying to let them connect to Dropbox with the old Datastore API with:

```
let accountManager = DBAccountManager.init(appKey: "...", secret: "...")
DBAccountManager.setSharedManager(accountManager)
DBAccountManager.sharedManager().linkFromController(self)
```

I am then taken to the Dropbox app on my phone where I hit **Allow** and then return to my app and get this error:

> Error Unknown: Unable to verify link request

Will I simultaneously be able to authenticate to the Datastore API and the new v2 API? If not, do you have some suggestions on how to access the user's data out of the datastore so I can put it in my own SQLite file?

Comment: I should also note that the authentication does *not* fail when I do this workflow in the simulator. Only when I'm authenticating via the Dropbox app on my device does it throw this error.

Comment: This looks similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605843/osx-dropbox-sync-api-error-unable-to-verify-link-request Take a look through to see if it helps.

Comment: Also, make sure you're not accidentally calling `linkFromController` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll see if I can get to the bottom of it.