# Dropbox open url not working iOS

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

I have been figuring out the issue since few hours now, I'm linking my app with dropbox.
I have created demo app and everything is working fine there, but as I have merged in my application, openurl delegate return false, I have created new app in dropbox and still the same issue.

### The error logs is :

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-2://1/connect" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme dbapi-2"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-8-emm://1/connect" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme dbapi-8-emm"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-2://1/connect" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme dbapi-2"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dbapi-8-emm://1/connect" - error:"This app is not allowed to query for scheme dbapi-8-emm"
[ERROR] unable to verify link request
[ERROR] DropboxSDK: credentials not saved. Make sure you call -[DBSession handleOpenUrl:] in your app delegate's application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method
```

Code in app delegate :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if DBSession.shared().handleOpen(url as URL!) {
        if DBSession.shared().isLinked() {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "didLinkToDropboxAccountNotification"), object: nil)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Here are some other posts with the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605843/osx-dropbox-sync-api-error-unable-to-verify-link-request
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235369/dropbox-datastore-to-api-2-migration-error Take a look over those, but in short, make sure you're not calling `linkFromController` multiple times, and that `NSUserDefaults` is working for your app.

Comment: Also, note that this SDK uses API v1, which is deprecated: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/

Answer (score 3):

for full tutorial see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/ios)

ensure once are you added the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your .plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>dbapi-2</string>
    <string>dbapi-8-emm</string>
  </array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>db-APP_KEY</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

**for your second Error : unable to verify link request**

```
func handleOpen(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
var expected: String = "\(self.appScheme())://\(kDBDropboxAPIVersion)/"
if !url.absoluteString.hasPrefix(expected) {
    return false
}
var components: [Any] = url.path.pathComponents()
var methodName: String = components.count > 1 ? components[1] : nil
if methodName.isEqual("connect") {
    var params: [AnyHashable: Any] = DBSession.parseURLParams(url.query)
    var token: String? = (params["oauth_token"] as? String)
    var secret: String? = (params["oauth_token_secret"] as? String)
    var userId: String? = (params["uid"] as? String)
    var state: String? = (params["state"] as? String)
    var nonce: String? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kDBLinkNonce)
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: kDBLinkNonce)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    if !nonce.isEqual(state) {
DBLogError("unable to verify link request")
return false
 }
self.updateAccessToken(token, accessTokenSecret: secret, for: userId)
}
if methodName.isEqual("cancel") {
DBLogInfo("DropboxSDK: user cancelled Dropbox link")
}
return true
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to post too :-)

Comment: i have added dbapi-2 and dbapi-8-emm in schemes, still i am getting 
error
[ERROR] unable to verify link request
[ERROR] DropboxSDK: credentials not saved. Make sure you call -[DBSession handleOpenUrl:] in your app delegate's application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik , please let me know where to add this code.

Comment: @Khushboo - in app delegate

Comment: see this link also https://github.com/dropbox-sdk-mirror/dropbox-sdk-ios/blob/master/DropboxSDK/Classes/DBSession%2BiOS.m

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, lot of use of unresolved identifiers errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134743/discussion-between-khushboo-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntely none of other answer worked, i deleted my app on dropbox and created new one, and did all process again
and voila, everything worked fine.