# DropboxSDK: credentials not saved

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox, dropbox-api, keychain

I have follow this tutorila to integrate Dropbox in my app

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-dropbox-integration

I had made a demo project before integrate into my main project . 
its working fine

When I add this code into my main project with same configuration , login page is appear and when I clicked for log in its says an error

> [ERROR] DropboxSDK: credentials not saved. Make sure you call
>   -[DBSession handleOpenUrl:] in your app delegate's application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method

How I can get rid off this ?

Comment: As said, call the [DBSession handleOpenUrl:]  method in your app delegate overridden method : - `(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

Comment: Then what should I do ? @iAviator

Comment: Then what should I do ? @iAviator

Comment: build and check if error exists.

Comment: till now same error ..

Comment: Are you using latest Dropbox framework? Also provide the code snippet where u see the error.

Comment: Here are some other posts with the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605843/osx-dropbox-sync-api-error-unable-to-verify-link-request
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235369/dropbox-datastore-to-api-2-migration-error Take a look over those, but in short, make sure you're not calling `linkFromController` multiple times, and that `NSUserDefaults` is working for your app.

Comment: Also, note that this SDK uses API v1, which is deprecated: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/